# Mounting mysql /var/lib/mysql on Azure File Share

Tags: mysql, azure

With Azure Container Apps, I'm trying to mount mysql on Azure file share, and the container shows running status but as soon as I enable ingress on TCP 3306, the container fails.

> InnoDB initialization has started. 2023-11-29T07:46:21.080825586Z
> 2023-11-29T07:46:21.080732Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot
> create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database
> was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
> 2023-11-29T07:46:21.080851835Z 2023-11-29T07:46:21.080772Z 1 [ERROR]
> [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic
> error. 2023-11-29T07:46:21.522932559Z 2023-11-29T07:46:21.522848Z 1
> [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
> 2023-11-29T07:46:21.523078071Z 2023-11-29T07:46:21.523019Z 0 [ERROR]
> [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
> 2023-11-29T07:46:21.523087930Z 2023-11-29T07:46:21.523040Z 0 [ERROR]
> [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting 2023-11-29T07:46:21.523454826Z
> 2023-11-29T07:46:21.523393Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server]
> /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  MySQL Community
> Server - GPL.

here is the yml for mysql container, where fs is the file share name created in Azure container apps

```
properties:
  configuration:
    activeRevisionsMode: Single
    dapr: null
    maxInactiveRevisions: null
    registries: null
    secrets: null
    service: null
  managedEnvironmentId: /subscriptions/<subid>/resourceGroups/ghostpoc/providers/Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments/ghostacaenv
  template:
    containers:
    - env:
      - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        value: somepass
      - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
        value: ghostdb
      - name: MYSQL_USER
        value: morepass
      - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
        value: morepass
      image: mysql:8.0
      name: db2
      volumeMounts:
      - volumeName: myvol
        mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      resources:
        cpu: 0.5
        ephemeralStorage: 2Gi
        memory: 1Gi
    initContainers: null
    revisionSuffix: ''
    serviceBinds: null
    terminationGracePeriodSeconds: null
    scale:
      maxReplicas: 10
      minReplicas: 0
      rules: null
    volumes:
    - name: myvol
      storageName: fs
      storageType: AzureFile
  workloadProfileName: null
resourceGroup: ghostpoc
type: Microsoft.App/containerApps
```